# Density function of uniform prob distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-function, uniform-distribution

Let $X ∼\operatorname{Uniform}(0,1)$. Find the density function of $Y = e^X$.

I got to:

$F_Y(y)$=$P(Y\le y)$=$P(e^X\le y)$=$P(X\le \ln(y))$

Not sure where to go from here?

Comment: What is $P(X<x)$ for $U(0,1)$ distribution?

Comment: It's just x.. ahhh

Comment: Then just integrate to get the probability, using that $X \sim U(0, 1)$. It's better to delimit the range of $y$ so that $e^X \leq y \Leftrightarrow X \leq \log y$ is always meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, you have
$$P(X\leq\ln(y))=F_X(\ln(y)),$$
where $F_X$ is the cumulative distribution function of $X$ ~ $U(0,1)$.